# How to handle an answer that should have been an edit to a previously posted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111839/python-3-4-2-idle-error-when-defining-denaryinput?noredirect=1#comment42728420_27111839), a user posted an answer to a question. Not much later, he posted another answer, starting with 'Also', which led me to believe it was meant to be an edit to the original, previously posted answer.

[image]

Content of the question aside, how should these situations be handled?
Flagging for a moderator seemed too much, but other flags are even less appropriate. Downvoting seemed wrong, because adding additional information is something I consider 'useful'.

An option that remains is to just comment on the second answer, point out that it should be an edit to the first, and hope that the author reads it and cares enough to take action.
Is that the way to go?

This has most likely happened before and I figured I could find an existing question on the matter, but couldn't.

---

**Edit:**

I proceeded as advised, flagged the answer as "not an answer" and posted a comment explaining the situation to the reviewers.

[image]

However, it got disputed

[image]

What is the next step? I suppose I could flag it again and hope for 'better' reviewers, but I'm not sure we are supposed to raise the same flag twice.

Comment: why is flagging too much? that's what appears appropriate

Comment: But why does the system allow multiple answers? That makes zero sense

Comment: @Coffee: because some problems can be solved in different ways. Both approaches can then be voted on separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would (1) flag as "not an answer" (these can be handled by the community, they do not automatically go to a diamond-mod) and (2) leave a comment explaining the situation so that the reviewers will be aware (since it's not always 100% obvious from context).

Comment: Part 2 of your answer is extra helpful, thanks. I'll go and do that now.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Comments certainly are shown on answers viewed through the Low Quality Posts review queue.

Answer (score 4):

Leave a comment *and* flag as Not An Answer.

I usually say:

> Please use the *Post Your Answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original post to add additional information.

The community will do the rest from the Low Quality review queue.

Easy-to-copy markdown:

`Please use the *Post Your Answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original post to add additional information.`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure you are aware the user who posted the 2 answers is not the person who asked the question. It's not meant to be an edit to the question, but an edit to the other answer

Comment: @TimCastelijns: it applies equally so to answers; I've adjusted the text to apply to either equally.

Comment: The button text is actually **Post Your Answer**

Comment: @DavidPostill: in this case it first shows *Add Another Answer* before showing the *Post Your Answer* button. But you are correct, that is now the text. My auto-comment predates a refresh that changed the text, I think.

Comment: Ok, makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

I would move the content into their existing answer and then edit the secondary answer to be a temporary stub indicating content moved (so it clearly is NAA any more).

I'd then downvote and (if possible) vote to delete the secondary answer.

I'd also leave a comment explaining that I'd consolidated the content and encouraging the OP to delete the obsolete answer themselves. Accompanied with a NAA flag in case they don't.

(I have no qualms about downvoting these as the user has already clicked through on a message box with the following text)

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
>
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing
>   answer, instead.

Comment: I moved the content, downvoted and tried to flag as NAA again, but it said "You flagged this post for moderater attention already", I'm not sure it's back in the flagged answers queue now. Is there anything at all in my power left to do?

Comment: @TimCastelijns - I found the answer and put in a vote to delete. It had one already so just needs one more which might happen if a 20K user happens upon it. I've flagged as NAA now as well.