# How to handle an obvious edit to the first answer posted as a second answer by the same user?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

To be more specific I am speaking about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950485/how-to-free-space-on-ubuntu-16-04/51950834#51950834). Its author has already posted an answer to the question and the second post was an obvious edit to the first one.

Here are the two posts (thanks to @pnuts):

[image: Answers to Q #51950485 now deleted]

As seen, I have commented the second post like that:

> If you have something to add, edit your answer and do not post another one.

And to my understanding I have flagged it as *Not an answer*, because the flag description says so:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. **It should possibly be an edit**, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

However, aparently it was wrong, because it was declined with the following reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

A similar question, *[How to flag an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276897/5366641)*, is well received and has a discussion in the comments, but it does not have an answer.

And according to the accepted answer of *[How to handle an answer that should have been an edit to a previously posted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277784/5366641)* I was right, which confuses me more about the reason the flag was declined.

Comment: Flagging that as NAA isn't that good in this situation, because the review queue doesn't show enough information to identify that flagged post as an edit attempt of another post. I would rather use a custom flag and explain the situation with a link to the other answer. This provides the necessary context to correctly handle the flag.

Comment: @Tom, I understand. That is why I open the post in a new tab when reviewing, in order to see all circumstances.

Comment: And that's a good approach, but a certain number of reviewers (I don't know if "many", "most" or "some") don't do that.

Comment: @Tom, that's why I also leave comments for the cases I think are more complicated. In this particular case I've also left one.

Comment: @scopchanov The point remains that you shouldn't be flagging if it's not very apparent that the flag is correct.  If the post looks like an answer, and you need to dig deeper to see that it's not, you should be explaining as much in the flag.

Comment: @Servy, When I use a custom flag with explanation, I get declines to use the standard ones. Furthermore, I strongly believe _a review_ means _review_ and not _click-through_. If one should go deeper to understand the case, then that is what is to be done.

Comment: @scopchanov If you're getting declines then you're either not flagging posts that aren't answers, or you're not writing a good flag message that explains why the post is NAA and why you didn't use the NAA flag.  In this case, something like, "This looks at a glance like an answer, but it's actually the question author explaining something they tried to do to debug the problem, and should have been an edit to the question."

Comment: And yes, when it's clear that a post is somehow problematic, but that the correct course of action is hard to determine, reviewers should either spend the time or skip.  The problem is when a post looks very much okay, but it's actually problematic for reasons that are not apparent.  That's the case here.  Reading the post, it reads just like an answer to the question.  Part of the problem here is also that *lots* of people are *constantly* flagging actual answers as NAA, because they're wrong, or short, or bad, or whatever.

Comment: It doesn’t look so obvious to me that the second answer should be an edit to the first one. These two answers are describing entirely different things. Since the first one is just one sentence and even fails to explain how it relates to the question, it might deserve a downvote, but that’s independent to the second answer. (With first, I mean the one posted earlier, which is the second one in your screenshot).

Comment: "I strongly believe a review means review" didn't you know that we only allowed keyboard mashing monkeys on those?

Comment: @Braiam, I am sorry, I didn't understand that.

Comment: It was sarcasm. People on meta will tell you that reviewers are not required to know anything about the thing they are reviewing about. In other words: keyboard smashing monkeys.

Comment: @Braiam Ahh, ok :)

Comment: @Braiam https://meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: So, why does the site let you answer more than once?

Comment: @Alvaro https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255359/add-another-answer-button-why-is-that-option-available

Comment: @Alvaro If it didn't, we wouldn't have great resources such as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113578/open-with-on-multiple-files), where someone repeatedly came up with new and interesting ways to answer my question each time the previous one wasn't appropriate.

Comment: Commenting on it is probably a good idea.

Comment: @Trilarion, commenting on what?

Comment: I think they mean commenting on the answer that you think should have been an edit.

Comment: @BSMP, I did so. :) Please see the screenshot.

Comment: They probably missed it.

Comment: @BSMP, most certainly.

Answer (score 5):

In this case I would downvote the `lsof` answer because it's incomplete and not particularly useful on its own, and leave a comment like

> this isn't an answer on its own; many files needed by your system aren't held open by running processes.  You could [edit] it into your existing answer as another section and delete this "answer".

(Hmm, the [edit] link will be to edit the post you comment under, so maybe get creative and `[edit](url-to-edit-the-other-answer)` to send them to the right edit link.)

This guides the OP into fixing the problem themselves, and alerts them to what they should have done.

---

It's not obvious how to use `lsof` at all for finding out which files / packages you can remove, so it definitely warrants a downvote.  And barely merits inclusion as a footnote / aside in another answer.

I guess you might suggest it as a final double-check before removing a package you weren't sure about, but it doesn't help you for something like a perl module where the files are read once but not kept open after process startup.

---

**If it had been an alternate but related method that could maybe be an answer**:

Unless it's truly totally unrelated, another section of the same answer is definitely better, and also a good option even if it is mostly unrelated.

Skip the downvote if the method is viable and explained in enough detail, or would be if combined with the first answer.  Still downvote if there's so little explanation that it's a bad answer, or a bad answer for another reason (like this case).

I usually only post multiple answers for something like an AVX512 vs. AVX2 version of something, when AVX512 has a new instruction that totally changes the approach to optimizing the function.

If both of my ideas are viable for the same use-case, I usually mention both in different sections, and maybe compare/contrast which things favour one vs. the other.

As well as not being an answer, the `lsof` suggestion was small and would fit nicely as an extra section.  (hrule with `---` and a bolded topic sentence works well to make sections, like I'm doing in this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see, why this should be an edit.
The user posted two different answers to the same question, which explain two different methods to solve the problem.

It is nice to separate it, so they can be voted individually (i.e. when one of the answers is not useful, while the other is) and linked individually. Furthermore, the texts are separated, so the asker knows that he should either use the one method *or* the other one, but not both.

> If you have something to add, edit your answer and do not post another one.

Is only true, if you have something to add to the same answer, not if you have an different answer.

---

I mean here the general idea of different answers to the same question, not the question in the OP in particular. I do not know how good the different answers were for the question and how exact they matched the question without the other one.

Comment: The shortest post is definitely not a _different method to solve the problem_. Furthermore, this was from the first posts queue, which means, that it is doubtful that the user knows how to properly use the system. Most of the newcomers do not. It is far more likely that he/she wanted to make an addition and not knowing how to edit, posted another answer.

Comment: I did not assess the actual correctness of the posts. And sadly the link is dead now, so I cannot look at the question again. But I did answer the question "how to handle two answers by the same user" with respect to two answers with totally different content. I would see it as "should be an edit" when he uses copy&paste, changes a minor thing and then re-posts as a new answer. But suggesting something else can deserve an own post. I see way too many "do this or do that and try this as well" posts. An answer is not a blog post where you compare different approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: I see your point, however, this is not the case that something else is suggested, which really deserves a separate answer. I know that because I also did read the question very carefully and interacted with the author too, since the question itself was off-topic.

Comment: Okay. So let's say my answer only addresses the general idea of multiple answers.

Comment: I agree with you on that. In turn, my question addresses, as stated, the _obvious edits_ (obvious, when the whole thread is cosidered, not just a post taken separately).

Comment: @scopchanov: The two answers appear to be unrelated approaches to the "how to free up space on Ubuntu".  The first is looking at removing unneeded packages, the `lsof` answer is to find what's running.  (Which is not an sufficient answer without further explanation; obviously there are lots of files that are needed but that aren't currently open as a file descriptor.)  I agree it's short enough that it should just be another section in the first answer, even though it's totally unrelated.

Comment: TL:DR: should have been an edit because it doesn't stand on its own.  It's more like a related suggestion you might want to mention in passing in a real answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes, _should have been an edit because it doesn't stand on its own. It's more like a related suggestion you might want to mention in passing in a real answer._ is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

> How to handle an obvious edit to the first answer posted as a second answer by the same user?

> **not an answer**
>   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be **an edit**, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

The flag dialog already tells you what to do. Is up to the reviewers to do due diligence or skip those items if they aren't able to.

Comment: In principle, sure. In practice... why would you trust random reviewers to even think that someone might have posted an apparently-legit answer that actually should be an edit, and read and comprehend all the other answers to determine whether this is the case? I ride a motorcycle. Do you think I _assume_ every other road user is intelligent and does their due diligence when changing lanes? Nuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu. Not in a million years.

Comment: @Clonkex why would any reviewer be able to not do due diligence in, well, reviewing? Is not that I trust them or not, is the explicit task they set themselves to do. If they aren't willing to do it correctly, they shouldn't be reviewing.

Comment: That's completely true, and I 100% agree that reviewers _should_ be reviewing correctly. But how do you define "correctly", and how much diligence is due? It's not immediately obvious that "NAA" could mean "I know it _looks_ like an answer, but it's added as though it's an edit, so it's actually not an answer". When it's that complicated it makes much more sense to actually explain the reason for flagging, instead of putting the onus on the reviewer to think of every possibility for the flag.

Comment: @Clonkex all that can be reasonable expected of a reviewer to do. Some situations are black and white, others are more complicated. If you find yourself trying to evaluate a complicated situation and aren't able to reach a desired conclusion, the *correct* action is to leave others to do so. In other words: be rational, critic and sensible.

Comment: Except that it's not obvious that it's a complicated situation. It immediately looks like an incorrect NAA flag (i.e. it appears to be black and white), so there's no reason to look any further. It's that simple.

Comment: @Clonkex it is not obvious that a C answer is posted to a Javascript question? It's not obvious that an answer to a JS question seems to be a markov chain? Those are the most "complicated" situations, but for you that know some JS is obvious. That's what reviewers should do, know what the heck they are reviewing and the context to do the sensible action.